# Java basic average number and random number

Tags: java, random, average

I was just practicing java programming by myself using random and averaging numbers but I was having a difficult time to do it. The program will ask "Enter # to be rolled between 0 to 100". Then I enter '3' then the output will be random 3 numbers. 
My question is after 3 numbers come out, I want to find the average of those numbers. For example, I want my output to be

```
Your # is 89
Your # is 50
Your # is 12
Your avg is ##(//whatever the avg of numbers)
```

My output is like

```
Enter # to be rolled between 0 to 100
3
Your # is 89
your avg is 29
Your # is 39
your avg is 13
Your # is 76
your avg is 25
```

Can you guys help me to solve this problem? I know my codes are mess.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ranEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random ranNumber = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        int ran;

        System.out.println("Enter # to be rolled "
                + "between 0 to 100");
        number = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
            ran=ranNumber.nextInt(100);

            System.out.println("Your # is " + ran);


            int avg=ran/number;

            System.out.println("your avg is " + avg);

        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: You aren't computing an average, you're dividing a random number by your count of numbers.

Comment: If you just want the average, define a variable that keeps the accumulate total, and then divide by the number of rolls.

Comment: Average = sum / count

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `avg` outside of the loop and then add all your numbers to it. It's also better to call it `sum` and define it as `double` to prevent rounding, this way you can divide it by `number` after the loop and get the average.

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
// ...
  sum += ran;
}
System.out.println("your avg is " + sum/number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
            ran=ranNumber.nextInt(100);

            System.out.println("Your # is " + ran);

            sum = sum+ran;

        }      
        System.out.println("your avg is " + sum/number);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's tested : 
user must enter a number integer :

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ranEx {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random ranNumber = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    int ran = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter A NUMBER  to be rolled "
            + "between 0 to 100");
    number = input.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        ran=ran+(ranNumber.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Your # is " + ran);
        int avg=ran/number;
        System.out.println("your avg is " + avg);
    }       
  }
}
```

output :

```
run:
Enter A NUMBER  to be rolled between 0 to 100
5
Your # is 95
your avg is 19
Your # is 107
your avg is 21
Your # is 178
your avg is 35
Your # is 274
your avg is 54
Your # is 338
your avg is 67
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the compute the average only once, *outside* the loop, after the loop generates the values. You could accomplish your goal as follows:

1. Intialize an accumulator variable to zero before the loop
2. Inside the loop, add each generated value to the accumulator
3. *After* the loop, divide the accumulator value by the number of values

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the average, define a variable that keeps the accumulate total, and then divide by the number of rolls.

```
// double for large values and decimal division later on
double total= 0;

int rolls = 4;
for ( int x = 0 ; x < rolls; x++ ) {

    total += x;
}

// calculate average
double average = total / rolls;

// validate that it works, ( ( 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 ) / 4 ) == 1.5
Assert.assertEquals( 1.5d, average );
```